# Hashvalue from SHA512 algorithm is 128 bits long?

Tags: c#, hash, sha512

I’ve a strange problem.
In my code I create a sha512 hash algorithm and sign some data with it.
Now I would expect the hash to be 512 bits long, but it’s 128.
What mistake have I made?

My Code:

```
var hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create( „SHA512“ );
var signedhHash = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.SignData( plainData, hashAlgorithm );
```

PS.
I’ve loaded the RSA keys from a file, which I’ve created with the following script:

```
makecert -r -n "CN=myCert" -sky exchange -sy 24 -sv myCert.pvk myCert.cer
cert2spc myCert.cer myCert.spc
pvk2pfx -pvk myCert.pvk -spc myCert.spc -pfx myCert.pfx –f
```

**Edit:**

I got the length from `signedhHash.Length`, which is equal to 128.

Comment: Where do you calculate the length?

Comment: Calculate the length? Do you mean something like: signedhHash.Length 
(signedhHash.Length is equals to 128)

Comment: You state "it's 128 bits long", where do you get that number?

Comment: If you get the length from signedhHash (128 *bytes*) then in reality you have 1024 *bits*. You're comparing two different things

Answer (score 3):

The hash value is 512 in size, but the *signed hash value* (from `SignData`) is 1024 in size.

```
var alg = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA512");
var hashArr = alg.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"));
var size = hashArr.Length * 8; //512

var rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var signedValue = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.SignData(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"), alg);
size = signedValue.Length * 8; //1024
```

(1 byte = 8 bits)

Comment: Some how I didn't see that there was an answer already posted when I came back to the page to post mine

Comment: Thank you very much!
So this will mean that signedhHash.Length is always equals to rsaCryptoServiceProvider.KeySize / 8?

Comment: @SpaceghostAli: When I started writing my comments on the OP, I didn't see this answer either.. Is Magnus a magician?

Answer (score 0):

The SignData does not return the hash made with the SHA512 algorithm it returns the signature for that hash made with the SignatureAlgorithm property of the provider (http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1)